# Two services share one Solr(through Sunspot)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I built a web service `A` which use `Solr` as its text search engine. There are on separate two machines.

Now I'm building a new service `B`. But because `B` is relatively small service, I don't want to build a its own `Solr`. Is there a way to have `A` and `B` share a `Solr` server, without messing their indexes up?

BTW they are both `Rails` services so I use `Sunspot` as an interface. I'm not sure whether it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create 2 Solr cores - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Comment: Don't forget to add the core path component to the solr path config for each app!